# Weird behaviour sorting in Tablesorter pluggin

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I'm using this great pluggin from JQuery called Tablesorter. The documentation is from https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html

If I sort via SQL, I get the expected behavior like this next image:

[image]

But when I sort via the tablesorter I get a wrong behavior as it is shown in the next image:

[image]

Is There an option to allow tablesorter sorting as SQL does?

I think that the problem only appears when the content is mixed with letters and numbers, but not sure at all.

Thank you very much for the help in advance!

Comment: @Mottie if you can help me will be so helpful...

Comment: without digging too much through the plugin it looks like the issue is the mix of alpha numeric characters which I didn't see support for in this plugin so you might need a custom solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the first cell contains all numeric values `010844005`. So the parser detection assumes that column is to be sorted numerically.

To fix this issue, set the column to sort by text. Do this by either:

- Setting a `sorter-text` class in the header cell

  ```
  <th class="sorter-text">Referencia</th>
  ```
- Setting the [`headers` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#headers) for that column

  ```
  $('table').tablesorter({
    headers: {
      0: { sorter: 'text' }
    }
  });
  ```

Comment: As always a pleasure to use your pluggin. Very useful.